# How to standardize many button events C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Could you tell me how to put together the many button event.

Writing all the many button event is bad Maintainability.
So I want to turn many button event into one method.
Like this...

Before

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button1 event
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button2event
}

private void buttonN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //buttonNevent       
}
```

After

```
private void buttonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    int index = int.Parse(btn.Name.Replace("button", ""));

    if(index==1)
    { 
        //button1 event
    }
    if(index==2)
    { 
        //button2 event
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is winforms, consider editing your question and adding the relevant UI tag. Instead double clicking the event, click the events tabs of the control and un the Click event type the `buttonClickEvent`

Comment: Well, in my eyes the second option is definitely the worse of the two... it has a really ugly smell, too many completely different responsibilities in one handler. If all Buttons (roughly) do the same thing - maybe just with different parameters -, then we could argue. But generally - no, that idea is bad and leads to even worse maintainability.

Comment: But if there is a valid use case here (which you're not suggesting), then a solution would be to assign all the handlers manually by hand or write some code to wire all buttons to one handler.

Comment: Actually, it depends how similar the code is for each button event.  We don't know that.

Comment: The ironic thing is that where you've written `//button1 event` if you replace that with real code, say: `button1_Click(sender, e);` Then you've basically walked around in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Web Forms I've solved this situation like this.

Define a general hidden button (this will be the trigger for all). You should define it "hidden" using the styles.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrintPdf" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" />
```

For the all other buttons "redirect" the click on the client side to the general one like this:

```
            btnPrintPlan.OnClientClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnPrintPdf, itemData.ClientIw.ID.ToString() + "|" + ((int)PrintDocs.NextStepsPlan).ToString()) + ";return false;";
            btnPrintNetWorth.OnClientClick = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnPrintPdf, itemData.ClientIw.ID.ToString() + "|" + ((int)PrintDocs.NetWorth).ToString()) + ";return false;";
```

As you can see, I use a Enum to define what I want to print by clicking different buttons.

The last part is to define the "general" button logic:

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sVal = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sVal))
            return;
        string[] tks = sVal.Split('|');
        if (tks.Length != 2)
            return;
        string sOrderId = tks[0];
        string sPrintType = tks[1];
        int orderId = 0;
        int iPrintType = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(sOrderId, out orderId) || !int.TryParse(sPrintType, out iPrintType))
            return;

        string sPdf = null;
        if (iPrintType == (int)PrintDocs.NextStepsPlan)
        {
           ....
        }//endif
        if (iPrintType == (int)PrintDocs.NetWorth)
        {
           ....
        }//endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Dictionary would be better than if's if you have hundreds of buttons.

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<object, EventArgs>> buttonEventMap = new  Dictionary<string, Action<object, EventArgs>>();

private void setup()
{
 buttonEventMap["button1"] = (object sender, EventArgs e)=>{Console.WriteLine("Button 1 Clicked");};
    
//  etc....
}

private void buttonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if( buttonEventMap.ContainsKey(btn.Name))
       buttonEventMap[btn.Name](sender, e);     
}
```

Although this still is't much different from just implementing each individual ButtonClickEvent.